# Flutter deep link there is no corresponding route in your app

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I have followed this link https://oemampedia.medium.com/how-to-do-deeplink-in-flutter-b0c9a7e1aa9d to use deep link in flutter.

My aim is to make the user click a link sent to his email address, and open this link through the flutter app, so that the user can confirm his email account. Nonetheless, the first time I click the link, it generates this error:

======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================

The following message was thrown:
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/api/v1/confirm_my_account?email=a.b@domain.com&Token=blahblahblah"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.

Apparently, after debugging, the line of code generating this error is

`stream.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((d) => _onRedirected(d));`

Can someone give me a clue on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This `"/api/v1/confirm_my_account?email=a.b@domain.com&Token=blahblahblah"` is definitely not a name of any route in your app. You are parsing the dynamic link wrong, and it's capturing all of it and assigning it as a route name.
You need to parse the part which has something like `/home_screen` or the name of any route in your app where you define them in main.

Comment: Can you take a look to this link as well <https://dev.to/mohitkyadav/handle-deep-links-in-the-android-apps-32mi>? I don't understand where is the code that triggers automatically to "/api/v1/confirm_my_account?email=a.b@domain.com&Token=blahblahblah"

Comment: Where can I parse the incoming link before the redirect occurs?